# Java executable jar file is not running properly

Tags: netbeans, executable, java

I have built an executable jar file using netbeans IDE, it works fine in my system but yesterday I gave it to my friend and he is complaining that the file is not running, it just show the splash screen and then closes, he has JRE 6 installed.

I am unable to resolve the issue. Can someone help?

Comment: what are the jar files used in project, Are you sure all are in classpath

Comment: Have your friend run it in a command line. There's probably an exception thrown, and it can be checked that way.

Comment: i have just three classes in my project, and thus i make a single jar file..i kept all classes in single class file and kept it at default package...its working fine on my pc...no matter in which so ever directory i place it, but not running on my friend's pc.

Comment: Probably different JDK to compile or missing library from third party.

Comment: which version of jdk do you have installed and which version of jdk does your friend has

Comment: @theTerribleSwftTomato- thats not the case....cuz i have done exception handling, created an error dialog box in it!!

Comment: @satya: i did it using jdk7, my friend doesn't have jdk cuz he is not a developer, he used jre6!!

Comment: can you ask him to upgrade his jre and then try

Comment: @rahul: That's the problem, you build the jar using JDK7 and you want to run it on JDK6. It will become error.

Comment: try looking for missing references like DB connection string etc in your code as these things dont get ported along with your jar and create exception which prevents it from running!!

Comment: am making him update his jre....lets hope everything works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you build the jar using JDK7 and you want to run it on JDK6. It will become error. Try to downgrade and build jar again using JDK6.

Right-Click on your project properties and select `Libraries` and change the Java Platform.

[image]

If the JDK6 didn't come out, please make sure to add it from `Tools > Java Platforms` and `Add Platform...`

[image]

Comment: this can be one of the possibilities as there is one more possibility of possible link breakage inside references in files. he may be pointing to some reference like a DB which is not present in remote location and thus an exception stops jar from executing!!

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you. But based on the comment for the question, I found that OP only has 3 classes inside the jar. Don't have any third party library and OP said that he build it using JDK7 when the friend running the jar file using JDK6. If this solution cannot help the OP, s/he can comment on my answer and I'll update my answer.